# Possible scenario for receiving SIP 487 Request Terminated message

Tags: sip

What are all the possible scenarios for an originating system to receive a 487 (Request Terminated) message from the destination end in response to an Invite message, before receiving 18X messages from the destination, and without any CANCEL message sent by the originator after sending the INVITE message?

Comment: The only time I have ever seen that response code used is when a CANCEL request has been received.

Answer (score 2):

The `487 Request terminated` is created only as reaction to the `CANCEL` request. Nevertheless the `CANCEL` may be generated by a stateful proxy. See the RFC-3261 chapter 16.10. A stateful proxy may generate the `CANCEL` due to timer expiration for example.

The `CANCEL` request must not be sent before a provisional response is received. But the provisional response do not need to be a 18x response. UAC or proxy may send `CANCEL` even after `100 Trying` is received. And moreover it is sufficient that the proxy receives a provisional response.

So there is the answer:
There are almost infinite number of all possible scenarios because there are plenty of SIP proxy implementations and their configurations and they may have a lot of reasons to cancel a transaction.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I knew that 487 message was a reply to CANCEL message but it was not sent by the originating server. Now, I have the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK. So if it answers your question then you can mark the question "answered".